# Is it possible to create a VIEW in sqlite3 using python script?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am familiar with python/sqlite3 interface. I've build a database with three tables using this and input data from various sources, etc. I have a separate ".sh"/notepad script I run after to create two views (one from each of two of the tables) followed by a final joined view created from the initial two views, ending with generating a final report and of course the db with additional info. Currently to run it, I just copy and paste that code after sqlite3 name.db.

My question: Is it possible to automate this by creating not only a simple VIEW but also a joined VIEW using the python/sqlite3 interface. ie: Use a connect/cursor/execute statement to create VIEW (not table)?

As an afterthought, it is probably possible to get this done with just the final joined view created from two initial tables, but I'll get back to that later at some point. Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Here is the code I have, but it is not creating views. It pulls from existing TABLE1 and TABLE2 after previous script creates db and tables, inputs data. No error message is given after.

```
db = "/path/to/db/dbfile"
def create_connection(sqliteDB):
     conn=None
     try:
          conn=sqlite3.connect(sqliteDB)
          return conn
     except Error as e:
          print(e)
     return conn

def create_view(conn, create_view_sql):
     try:
          c=conn.cursor()
          c.execute(create_view_sql)
     except Error as e:
          print (e)

def main(db):
     database = db

     sqlite_create_view1 = """CREATE VIEW view1 as
     select id, b, c from TABLE1;"""

     sqlite_create_view2 = """CREATE VIEW view2 as
     select id, d, e, f from TABLE2;"""

     sqlite_create_final = """CREATE VIEW final as
     select a.id, a.b, a.c, b.id, b.d, b.e, b.f 
     from view1 a
     left join view2 b using (id); """

     conn.create_connection(database)
     conn.text_factory = str

     if conn is Not None:
          create_view (conn, sql_create_view1)
          create_view (conn, sql_create_view2)
          create_view (conn, final)

     else:
          print ("Error - cannot update view")
```

Comment: You can create views from Python's sqlite library just like you create tables or indexes or whatever else. Just execute the appropriate statement. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html

Comment: What do you mean by *...but it is not creating views...*? Did you check the db?

Comment: I did, the code runs without an error, but no view is created. I'm using the same format as how I created the tables. Not sure if missing something...

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. If you work with `sqlite` in python the easiest way is to use `connection.execute`. Using this command you can do everything.

Here is snippet to:

1. create table
2. insert two dummy rows
3. select from table
4. create view script
5. select from view script

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

conn.execute("CREATE TABLE t (id int, name TEXT)")

conn.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'row1')")
conn.execute("INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'row2')")

print(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM t").fetchall())

conn.execute("""
CREATE VIEW view_t as
SELECT * FROM t """)

print(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM view_t").fetchall())
```

And of course you can create view which contains `JOIN`. Here is example using table from previous snippet and `SELF JOIN`:

```py
conn.execute("""
CREATE VIEW view_tt as
SELECT * FROM t as t1 
 JOIN t as t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
""")

print(conn.execute("SELECT * FROM view_tt").fetchall())
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(1, 'row1', 1, 'row1'), 
(2, 'row2', 1, 'row1'), 
(2, 'row2', 2, 'row2')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and not being rude like others on here. I edited my question and added code snippet. Any further comments is much appreciated!!!
Creating the views is done in a separate script from how the db itself (and tables) are created.

Comment: Do you always have to write a full selecte like `SELECT * FROM view_tt` to select from a view or is there a simpler syntax where you could just pass its name?

Comment: you can create simple dict, which will act as query repository. For example: `queries= dict(view_tt="SELECT * FROM view_tt")` then you can reference complete select using only key `'view_tt'`.  `print(conn.execute(queries['view_tt']).fetchall())`.